# ASP.NET Core + Docker not accessible on specified port

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, containers, kestrel

It is impossible for me to access container with ASP.NET Core 3.1 application running inside.
Goal is to run application in container on port 5000. When I'm running it locally using standard VS profile I navigate to **http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html** in order to load swaggerUI. I would like to achieve same thing using docker.

**Steps to reproduce my issue:**

- Add dockerfile with exposed **5000** port and **ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS**  variable:

  ```
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
  WORKDIR /app
  ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
  EXPOSE 5000

  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
  WORKDIR /src
  COPY ["myapp/myapp.csproj", "myapp/"]
  RUN dotnet restore "myapp/myapp.csproj"
  COPY . .
  WORKDIR "/src/myapp/"
  RUN dotnet build "myapp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

  FROM build AS publish
  RUN dotnet publish "myapp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

  FROM base AS final
  WORKDIR /app
  COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
  ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
  ```
- Build image

  ```
   docker build -t myapp .
  ```
- Run docker image:

  ```
   docker run myapp -p 5000:5000
  ```

Running commands above with specific docker file results in this:

```
    [21:28:42 INF] Starting host.
    [21:28:42 INF] Now listening on: http://[::]:5000
    [21:28:42 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
    [21:28:42 INF] Hosting environment: Production
    [21:28:42 INF] Content root path: /app
```

However, I can't access container using http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html because of ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED -> This site can't be reached.

I did get into container to check if host is running for sure, using:

```
docker exec -it containerId /bin/bash
cd /app
dotnet myapp.dll
```

what resulted in following error:

```
Unable to start Kestrel.
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://[::]:5000: address already in use.
```

Conclusion is that port inside the container is used, application is alive, it's just not accessible from outside.I don't know how to get inside of it.
Please point me into right direction.

**UPDATE**
Issue is solved, answer is posted below. However explanation why it was needed and how it works would be nice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve the issue I had to manually add "--server.urls" to entrypoint like shown below:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll", "--server.urls", "https://+:5000"]
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved the same issue in the following way:

1. Added the following in `appsettings.json` to force Kestrel to listen to port  80.

```
"Kestrel": {
  "EndPoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://+:80"
    }
  }
}
```

2. Exposed the port in `dockerfile`

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "EntryPoint.dll"]
```

3. Ran the container using the below command.

```
docker run -p 8080:80 <image-name>:<tag>
```

4. The app exposed on `http://localhost:8080/`

Answer (score -1):

Just two other hints, ENV variables are scoped in build-stages and will not be preserved. (It is not in your case).
Also the publish command in VS is set by default to Release and the initial program.cs has an

```
if ( app.Environment.IsDevelopment() ) 
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

clause. So swagger will not be available.